# Specifying output files for a copy task in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a task which copies a bunch of files from one location into another. It looks like:

```
task copyStuff (type: Copy) {
    from tempDir
    into buildDir
}
```

Where `tempDir` and `buildDir` are simply Strings. I'm attempting to specify the inputs and outputs of the task to avoid doing it when not necessary, but am having some trouble with the outputs specifically. The inputs are easy:

```
task copyStuff (type: Copy) {
    inputs.dir tempDir
    from tempDir
    into buildDir
}
```

But how to specify the outputs in this case? The `buildDir` can have other things on it, not just the files being copied, so I think I need to specify the `outputs.files` specifically using the files being copied in. However, I'm unsure of the best way to do that.

Outside of the task, should I loop over the files in the tempDir, and create a list of files similar, but in the buildDir instead? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to declare inputs or outputs as the `Copy` task already does it for you. Same for other tasks that ship with Gradle.

Comment: Hmmm... the `outputs.file` returns the destination folder, not the files copied into the destination folder, as the OP suggests. AIUI this is a current shortcoming (https://discuss.gradle.org/t/copy-task-outputs-dont-reflect-files-actually-copied/1135).

Comment: What if I want to define extra inputs (dependencies)? For example, `project.version` -> A -> B where A is an input file and B is an output file. A and B remain the same, but the version changes. Hence, the copy action should be performed. “does it for you” is nice if it can also be adjusted.

Comment: Alternative solution https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-clean-rule-deletes-the-entire-directory-files-instead-of-the-task-output-files/14424/2